# render :update on Rails 3.1.0 gives me Missing Template update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, link-to, link-to-remote

I'm working with `rails 3.1.0` and this is my first application on `3.1.0`

I have a `remote` link:

```
link_to "my link",{:controller=>"my_controller",:action=>"my_action"},:remote=>true
```

and in `my_controller` I have

```
def my_action
    @data = Data.all
    render :update do |page|
        page.replace_html "show_data",:partial=>"data_partial"
    end
end
```

but then in the log I get an error

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template my_controller/update...
```

and I was checking at this post 
http://wowkhmer.com/2011/09/19/unobtrusive-ajax-with-rails-31/

do I really need to use a `coffee script` or a `js.jrs` to do this thing ??

Comment: above should work check again by `restarting server` OR if you have file `app/my_controller/_data_partial.html.erb`

Comment: Seems like in `Rails 3.1` the `render :update` won't work since they're getting everything separated and that's why javascript will only be used and interpreted in `.js` files check that post i put a link on my question workd perfectly for me.

Comment: try `render :update=>true do |page| ...etc...`.

Comment: try `render 'update'`

Answer (score 0):

Javascript integration doesn't work this way anymore. `render :update ...` tries to render the update action, which doesn't have an associated template. You need to move that out of the controller and into the view code, in app/views/my_controller/my_action.js.erb:

`$("show_data").update("<%= escape_javascript(render :data_partial) %>");`